# How to solve memory usage increase and slower in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

Hi I'm doing some image processing. I have some problems when code running
maybe... at least 1 hour code running well. But when the times on and on my code speed is getting slower and memory usage increase.
I try to find some information about these problems. people use list comprehension or map func.
Are these the only solutions?

```
x_array = np.array([])
y_array = np.array([])
present_x_array = np.array([])
present_y_array = np.array([])
cnt = 0

for x in range(curve.shape[1]):
    if np.max(curve[:, x]) > 200 :
        for y in range(curve.shape[0]):
            if curve[y,x] > 200 :
                present_x_array = np.append(present_x_array, x)
                present_y_array = np.append(present_y_array, y)
            else:
                continue
        if cnt == 0:
            x_array = present_x_array
            y_array = present_y_array
            cnt = cnt + 1
        else :
            if abs(np.max(y_array) - np.max(present_y_array)) <= 10 :
                x_array =np.append(x_array, present_x_array)
                y_array =np.append(y_array, present_y_array)
            else :
                continue
        present_x_array = np.array([])
        present_y_array = np.array([])

    else:
        continue
```

I try to make comprehension but it stucks handle 'cnt == 0' and 'cnt = cnt + 1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x_array =np.append(x_array, present_x_array)` - `np.append` creates a new copy whenever you append. Therefore, as the array size increase, the copy operation gets expensive.
I would advise replacing `np.array` with `list` to avoid unnecessary copy operations. The list append is fast.

Reference: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17090

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I thought numpy appends were faster than list appends, but that's not the case. I will try to change those things

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, there might be some way to do the trick:

1, Replace those if statements with np.where().

2, Turn your whole loop into a function or class.

Hope this could help.

Have a nice coding day.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your specific advice. Actually I already functionize that code but I didn't try 1st advice. I will find the np.where and apply it